# Server Side Events - Only look for new data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I got a suggestion to use Server Side Events for jQuery when I poll my notification system. I did a try with it but it still seem to be spamming the log with old data - and I want it to send all data it can find once and then only post new data. How can this be accomplished?

PHP

```
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');

        $data["notifications"] = $this->db->select("*")
            ->where("user_id", $user_id)
            ->order_by("time_received", "desc")
            ->get("members_notifications")
            ->result();

            echo "event: getNotifications\n";
            echo "data: ".json_encode($data["notifications"])."\n";
            echo "\n";
```

jQuery

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var user_id = <?php echo $this->session->userdata("id"); ?>;

                var sse = $.SSE("http://localhost/index.php/_notifications/3", {
                    events: {
                        getNotifications: function(e){
                           $.each(JSON.parse(e.data), function(index, value){
                                console.log(value.content);
                           });
                        }
                    }
                });

                sse.start();
            });
```

Comment: either client or server is going to have to keep track of what's already been sent in the current session